# SEO en sitios hechos con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo

Tengo un sitio web que incluye una página por sección. Quiero implementar algunas de las ventajas de AngularJS en el mismo y unificar cada sección en un solo documento.

¿Qué prácticas debo implementar para no perder presencia en los buscadores? ¿Cómo hago para que cada meta tag se diferencie entre secciones tal cual se encuentran en cada página?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para modificar los tags meta,links y title en una aplicación con AngularJs te recomiendo el siguiente package que he utilizado en varios proyectos.

https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-update-meta

Sobre estrategias SEO hay mucha información en la red, pero mira siempre de encontrar artículos recientes.

En mi caso, los tags que siempre actualizo según las vistas son:

```
  <title>...</title>
  <meta name="description" content=...>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
```

Si el site es multiidoma (y se selecciona el idioma vía url)

```
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="...." />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="...." />
```

Para evitar el contenido duplicado (por ejemplo, usas parámetros en la url para paginación o filtros)

```
<link rel="canonical" href="...." />
```

Si usas AngularJs y como no todos los crawlers renderizan javascript tambien te recomiendo que mires el siguiente middleware:

https://prerender.io/

Espero que te ayude

Un saludo